# MySQL trigger result - 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers, mysql-error-1064

i need to create a trigger in sql to do the following:
Wordpress Table 'options' has in id 1 and id 2 the option_value URL of the Website.

If that URL gets changed in that particular place (id 1 & id2), the trigger should run to set back to old.option_value

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_up_otpions_value
BEFORE UPDATE ON option_value FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:old.option_value = 'https://example.com') then
:new.option_value := 'https://example.com';
end if;
end;
```

but i get the following error:

```
#1064 - Error ':old.option_value = 'https://example.com') then
    :new.option_value := 'h...' Row 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `:` sign from the old and new values

Also you need to add set keyword.

After that, if you have a table that looks something like this:

```
create table Zr_options (option_value varchar(500))
```

then this BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER will work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_up_otpions_value
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON Zr_options FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.option_value = 'https://example.com' then
        set new.option_value = 'https://example.com';
    end if;
end;
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d383465a49a96c377a8e4c5f45205769)

Comment: i did like you explained, 

1. create table option_value(option_value varchar(500))
2. INSERT INTO option_value VALUES('http:test')
3. INSERT INTO option_value VALUES('https://example.com')
4. CREATE TRIGGER tr_up_otpions_value
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON option_value FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF old.option_value = 'https://example.com' then
        set new.option_value := 'https://example.com';
    end if;
end;

but that gives me the same error: 
#1064 - Error in SQL-Syntax.  '' Line 6

Comment: Hi @max can you share the entire error with me ? As xou can see here.: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6de4f0dea0054feb8927979769c00d1c all works ok...

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/fG5DSR5) i attached a screenshot of the table, maybe it helps. 

[link](https://postimg.cc/R3dnJNpk) and this is the error Message

Comment: Hello @max, from your error picture there is one part missing: `;
    end if;
end;` 

is this because the picture is cut off or ?

Comment: yes table name is Zr_options and in that there is a option_value with a url inside, if that url gets changed it should trigger to old.value of option_value in option_id 1 or 2

Comment: Please check my code again for your trigger. I have changed it. The able name must be in the create table code (`ON Zr_options FOR EACH ROW`)!! You have said you have created the option_value table but your table is Zr_options.

Comment: thx. i changed that, but still have the same error

#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei '' in Zeile 6

Row 6 is this:         set new.option_value := 'https://example.com';

Comment: Hi @max can you send me the new image with the error code

Comment: [error](https://postimg.cc/xcbQXhFY) this is the error message, but it looks same

Comment: Your table is called Zr_options, not zr_option! Add the s!

Comment: i changed that, but still, get the very same error message

Comment: Also, please add to the image the entire code because I can see only fierst part

Comment: [sql](https://postimg.cc/LhPRXGWS) this is the sql of it

Comment: Hi @max Please remove `:` in the 6th line

Comment: Please try to add delimiter before and after like on this link https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-before-update-trigger/#:~:text=MySQL%20BEFORE%20UPDATE%20triggers%20are,table%20associated%20with%20the%20triggers.&text=In%20this%20syntax%3A,time%20to%20invoke%20the%20trigger.

Comment: Hi @max, please can you tell me how does one select(that works) form this table looks like ? For example does this work: `select option_value from Zr_options` ?